# How to prevent microphone batteries from going dead by mistake?

Tags: streaming, camera, automation

I have a home setup for doing video calls where I've got a Panasonic Lumix G7 with a Rode VideoMic Pro attached in its P2 jack. These are then fed into a USB capture card and connected to my computer.

Throughout the day and the varied video calls, I turn on and off the camera as required (and put on the lens cover), but I keep forgetting about the mic. Since it uses phantom power from a 9V battery, it's not uncommon that I leave it running for a whole night before coming back the next day. This microphone has an LED indicator in the back which is hard to notice, compared to the camera that has a whole display that tells me its still running or not.

Other than obviously remembering to shut it down after each use, is there anything I can do to "automate" away the task of shutting down the microphone?